# Execution time java program

Tags: performance, time, runtime, physics

First of all, here's just something I'm curious about

I've made a little program which fills some templates with values and I noticed that every time I run it the execution time changes a little bit, it ranges from 0.550s to 0.600s. My CPU is running at 2.9GHZ if that could be useful.

The instructions are always the same, is it maybe something that has to do with physics or something more software oriented?

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with java running on a virtual machine; even a c program might run different times slightly longer/shorter, also the operating system steers when a program has resources (cpu time, memory …) to be executed.